# PHP: Cookiefile for each logged in user?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm using curl to make an external call when the user clicks a button. It seems that I need to use a cookiefile / cookiejar to store some temporary information because it would not work otherwise.

Here's a code extract:

```
  if (!is_dir("/tmp/cookies"))
    mkdir("/tmp/cookies");

$cookie_path = "/tmp/cookies/$idHash";

    function curl_cookie_set($submit_url)
    {

    global $cookie_path;
    //sets the cookie file so the post function will work correctly

    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_path); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
}
```

Currently, I'm creating a new cookie file for every user but was wondering if this is the most efficient way to go about it. Is there a way to store the cookie information in the session variable? Or is it possible (and feasible) to store it all in one file? What are your thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing already as unefficient thing as a network call and you're worrying about just a little text file?